# How to delete/rename multiple columns with Room Auto-Migration

Tags: android, android-room

**Note**: Room Auto Migration is in Beta - [2.4.0-beta02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.4.0-beta02)

I've deleted two columns in two different tables. And I tried repeat the `@DeleteColumn` annotation, like so

```kotlin
    @DeleteColumn(tableName = "User", columnName = "phone")
    @DeleteColumn(tableName = "Product", columnName = "description")
    @DeleteTable(tableName = "Category")
    class TestRoomAutoMigration: AutoMigrationSpec {   }
```

but I get this error

```
Repeatable annotations with non-SOURCE retention are not yet supported
```

**Questions**

1. How delete/rename multiple columns if I can't repeat the annotation with Auto Migration

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Kotlin has yet to add full support for repeatable annotations with the same syntax as Java. So we'll have to use the container annotation, like this:

```kotlin
@DeleteColumn.Entries(
    DeleteColumn(tableName = "User", columnName = "phone"),
    DeleteColumn(tableName = "Product", columnName = "description"),
)
@DeleteTable(tableName = "Category")
class TestRoomAutoMigration: AutoMigrationSpec {   }
```

This works for renaming columns too.

This was first answered on the Google issue tracker - [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194642288)

Comment: Works with renaming too

Comment: @HussienFahmy Thank you. I've updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: How to change columnType?

Comment: @donmj Changing the column type is out of scope for this SO question. But what I remember is there is not "alter column" in sqlite. So there won't be in Room. Which means you will have to manually migrate data from the old column to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin is now supports repeatable annotations in version 1.6

`org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0`